# String to const char conversion using c_str() or toCharArray()?

Tags: c++, string, arduino, char, type-conversion

I want to know more about programming and after a bit of googling I found how to convert a string to a const char.

```
String text1;
```

What I do not understand is why c_str() works,

```
const char *text2 = text1.c_str();
```

contrary to toCharArray()?

```
const char *text2 = text1.toCharArray();
```

or

```
const char text2 = text1.toCharArray();
```

The latter is more logical to me as I want to convert a  string to a char, and then turn it into a const char. But that doesn't work because one is a string, the other is a char. The former, as I understand, converts the string to a C-type string and then turns it into a const char. Here, the string suddenly isn't an issue anymore oO

.

a) Why does it need a C-type string conversion and why does it work only then?

b) Why is the pointer needed?

c) Why does a simple toCharArray() not work?

.

Or do I do something terribly wrong?

Thanks heaps.

I am using PlatformIO with Arduino platform.

Comment: What makes `String` better than `std::string`?

Comment: @Ted does arduino have `std::string`? I thought they omitted a lot of those good things for size or memory reasons or something.

Comment: I haven't understood that yet, to be honest. But using String vs std::string somehow doesn't create issues. I think String is equivalent to charArray or so. PlatformIO highlights it as "Class".

Comment: @JohnFilleau It doesn't ship with a standard library implementation. But you can get them seperatly.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Sure. It's uses a c++ compiler so any standard library implementation should work. https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/arduino-stl is a good start.

Comment: @TedLyngmo sure, I wasn't questioning whether it could be compiled. I was curious whether arduino came "`std::string`-ready". Seems like a lot of extra work when `String` works good enough, and out of the box. Actually looking at the interface I'm not sure *why* they didn't just provide `std::string` instead of this `String`. Maybe the original implementation of `String` was much weaker to match the first arduinos?

Comment: I guess the Arduino IDE is a lightweight system bc the microcontroller have limited memory. I use PlatformIO supporting std::string etc. However, still don't know why I need to convert to a C-type String first?

Comment: @JohnFilleau The IDE has a menu for adding the STL lib - it's not a lot of work. If you are going to program C++ on an Arduino, it's sort of mandatory to install the STL.

Comment: @Ted I didn't realize the IDE had such immediate support. Thanks for taking the time to clarify.

Comment: @nolimits we can't tell you why you have to convert to a c-style string. You're the one doing it. Why are you doing it? What function are you calling that requires a c-style string?

Comment: Being unfamiliar with the Arduino String, i've looked at the docs. c_str method seems to be std::string like, and does, indeed, return a pointer to an internally managed buffer, so as long as you keep the original object alive and untouched, you are fine (just like with std::string). But toCharArray doesn't even return anything. It receives your own buffer instead and a max size of characters to copy into it. Your 2 last attempts shouldn't even compile. What am i reading wrong?

Comment: That's how I'm reading it as well, @Boris.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### If you need to modify the returned c-style string in any way, or have it persist after you modify the original `String`, you should use `toCharArray`.

#### If you only need a null-terminated c-style string to pass as a read-only parameter to a function, use `c_str`.

---

[Arduino reference for `String.toCharArray()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/tochararray/)

[Arduino reference for `String.c_str()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/c_str/)

The interface (and implementation) of `toCharArray` is shown below, from [source](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/WString.h)

```
    void toCharArray(char *buf, unsigned int bufsize, unsigned int index=0) const
        { getBytes((unsigned char *)buf, bufsize, index); }
```

So your first issue is that you're trying to use it incorrectly. `toCharArray` will **COPY** the underlying characters of your `String` into a buffer that you provide. This must be extra space that you have allocated, either in a buffer on the stack, or in some other writable area of memory. You would do it like this.

```
String str = "I am a string!";
char buf[5];
str.toCharArray(buf, 5);
// buf is now "I am\0"

// or you can start at a later index, here index 5
str.toCharArray(buf, 5, 5);
// buf is now "a st\0"

// we can also change characters in the buffer
buf[1] = 'X';
// buf is now "aXst\0"

// modifying the original String does not invalidate the buffer
str = "Je suis une chaine!";
// buf is still "aXst\0"
```

This allows you to copy a string partially, or at a later index, or anything you want. Most importantly, this array you copy into is mutable. We can change it, and since it's a copy, it doesn't affect the original `String` we copied it from. This flexibility comes with a cost. First, we have to have a large enough buffer, which may not be known at compile time, and takes up memory. Second, that copying takes time to do.

---

But what if we're calling a function that just wants to read a c-style string as input? It doesn't need to modify it at all?

That's where `c_str()` comes in. The `String` object has an underlying c-string type array (yes, null terminator and all). `c_str()` simply returns a `const char*` to this array. We make it `const` so that we don't accidentally change it. An object's underlying data should not be changed by random functions outside of its control.

This is the ENTIRE code for `c_str()`:

```
const char* c_str() const { return buffer; }
```

You already know how to use it, but to illustrate a difference:

```
String str = "I am another string!";
const char* c = str.c_str();
// c[1] = 'X'; // error, cannot modify a const object

// modifying the original string may reallocate the underlying buffer
str = "Je suis une autre chaine!";
// dereferencing c now may point to invalid memory
```

Since `c_str()` simply returns the underlying data pointer, it's fast. But we don't want other functions to be allowed to modify this data, so it's `const`.

Comment: Thanks heaps!!!! I am just curios at this point; The String has \0 whereas c_str doesn't? I try to figure out why I can't send text Strings to Nextion displays [1] and have to convert them to char arrays first. What might be the difference? [1] https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=671154.0

Comment: the `const char*` you receive from `c_str()` is null terminated, just like the buffer you fill from `toCharArray()`. They're both null terminated (end in `\0`, which has numeric value 0)